# How to stop other ajax functions executing automatically while calling single ajax function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have ajax functions written for getting data from server on click.

### Flow

1)  Browse  -> click -> We get Years. [working]

2)  Years  -> click -> We get Months. [working]

3)  Month  -> click  -> We get week of that month.[working]

All the three function get data from server.

But when i click  on year to get months ,

### 2 functions are fired

1) get months which i clicked .

2) get year, which was only called by Browse link ( this function is called automatically). So again get year function is called after get months function executes.

Similarly i had 3rd function which returns week of that month.
When i click on any month to get week, 3 function are called

1) To get week - called by me on click.

2) To get months - called automatically.

3) To get years - called automatically.

### 2 functions i had listed below

1) getYear
2) getMonth

### function getYears()

```
function getYears() {

        var ul = $('.panel-body ul');
        if (ul.length > 0) {
            ul.html('');
        }
        var liopen = '<li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" onclick="getMonths(this);">';
        var liclose = '</a></li>';

        //showing progress bar
        progress.fadeIn(500);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Test.aspx/loadYears",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                progress.fadeOut(500);
                var obj = JSON.parse(data.d);
                console.log(obj);
                for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                    ul.append(liopen + obj[i] + liclose);


               }

            },
            error:function(errorData)
            {
                console.log(errorData.status);
            }
        });
    }
```

### function getMonths(target)

```
function getMonths(target) {


        progress.fadeIn(500);
        var targetLink = $(target);
        var ifData = $(target).find('ul');
        if (ifData.length > 0) {
            ifData.html('');
        }
        var ul = $(document.createElement('ul'));

        var liopen = '<li><a href="#" onclick="getWeeks(this);">';
        var liclose = '</a></li>';
        var year = parseInt( $(target).text());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Test.aspx/loadMonths",
            data:'{year_ : "' + year + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                progress.fadeOut(500);
                var obj = JSON.parse(data.d);
                console.log(obj);
                for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                    ul.append(liopen + obj[i] + liclose);


                }
                targetLink.append(ul);
                return true;
            },
            error: function (errorData) {
                console.log(errorData.status);
            }
        });
    }
```

### Browse

```
<a href="#" style="z-index:3;color:grey" onclick="getYears();">Browse Site reports</a>
```

---

```
<ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" onclick="getMonths(this);">2016</a></li></ul>
```

---

```
<ul><li><a href="#" onclick="getWeeks(this);">Jul</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: can you plz also post the click handler where `getYears() ` is called?

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rathore/y3o0ct1p/   , i just put the html code. @dreamweiver

Comment: Have you tried to add async:false to your ajax calls?

Comment: @Bardo tried, not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that all the data was appending to "a" tag itself.
So if we click in getMonths function, which is nested in main  tag itself, 
we are clicking the  tag also .
Like code below:

```
<a click=func1();>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a click=function2();>
      </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
</a>
```

issue solved.